# How to import all csv files in one folder and make the filename the variable name in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to automatically import all csv files that are in one folder as dataframes and set the dataframe's variable name to the respective filename.

For example, in the folder are the following three files: data1.csv, data2.csv and data3.csv

How can I automatically import all three files having three dataframes (data1, data2 and data3) as the result?

Comment: Instead of dynamically creating variables on the fly, I'd suggest you use a dictionary to hold your dataframes. Use the filenames as keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save dataframe as variable with own file name. But it is not secure. This could cause code injection.

```
import pandas
import os

path = "path_of_directory"
files = os.listdir(path) # Returns list of files in the folder which is specifed path

for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".csv"):# Checking wheter file endswith .csv
        # os.sep returns the separtor of operator system
        exec(f"{file[:-4]} = pandas.read_csv({path}+{os.sep}+{file})")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible that some quotation marks are missing here:  `{path}+{os.sep}+{file}`? For me it only works with `'{path}'+'{os.sep}'+'{file}'`. And what exactly is the risk of code injection?

Comment: Will you use this code in a website or something public? This exec method executes parameter as like normal python code. Danger is file name . For instance if filename includes a space, this code will cause a error, or if filename starts with a digit this code will cause a error. As you know variable name cannot start with a digit, or can't include a space. This is only a example. In my opinion you should use dictionary instead of variable, because it is secure, faster and more convient for your situation. If you want more check this out : https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

Since the answer that was given includes an exec command, and munir.aygun already warned you what could go wrong with that approach. Now I want to show you the way to do it as Justin Ezequiel or munir.aygun already suggested:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

# Path to your data
path = r'D:\This\is\your\path'

# Get all .csv files at your path
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

# Read in the data from files and safe to dictionary
dataStorage = {}
for filename in allFiles:
    name = os.path.basename(filename).split(".")[0]
    dataStorage[name] = pd.read_csv(filename)

# Can be used then like this (for printing here)
if "data1" in dataStorage:
    print(dataStorage["data1"])
```

Hope this can still be helpful.

Comment: this is the only variation that worked for me, the other examples give syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the directory using pathlib and build a dictionary of name->DataFrame, eg:

```
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

dfs = {path.stem: pd.read_csv(path) for path in pathlib.Path('thepath/').glob(*.csv')}
```

Then access as `dfs['test1']` etc...